# Can't add cell to UITableView from Modal VC to Table VC (complicated)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, tableview, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to add a cell to my table view controller from a modal view controller. My data source array has multiple properties (name, time interval). Right now I have a delegate/protocol in my modal view controller that sends the data to the table view controller. However, for some reason I can add the data to the array but I can't add a cell to the tableview with that data. Here is my code:

ToDoTableViewController.h (TableViewController)

```
 @interface ToDoTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, Properties2ViewControllerDelegate>
{
IBOutlet UIView *headerView;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *taskArray;
-(UIView *)headerView;
-(IBAction)addCell:(id)sender;
```

ToDoTableViewController.m (TableViewController)

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [[self tableView] setDataSource:self];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
[[cell textLabel] setText:[taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    return cell;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [taskArray count];
}
-(IBAction)addCell:(id)sender{
    Properties2ViewController *pvc = [[Properties2ViewController alloc]init];
    [pvc setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
-(UIView *)headerView{
    if (!headerView){
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil];        
    }
    return headerView;
}
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self headerView];
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[self headerView] bounds].size.height;
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
    }
-(void)properties2ViewControllerDidEnterPropertiesSuccesfully:(Tasks *)t{
    [taskArray addObject:t];
}
```

Properties2ViewController.h (ModalViewController)

```
    @class Tasks;
@protocol Properties2ViewControllerDelegate;

@interface Properties2ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{
__weak IBOutlet UITextField *taskName;
__weak IBOutlet UIButton *doneButton;
    __weak IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) Tasks *testTask;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <Properties2ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
-(IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
@end

@protocol Properties2ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)properties2ViewControllerDidEnterPropertiesSuccesfully:(Tasks *)t;
@end
```

Properties2ViewController.m (ModalViewController)

```
-(IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender{
    testTask = [[Tasks alloc]initWith:[taskName text] :[datePicker countDownDuration] :[NSDate date]];
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector (properties2ViewControllerDidEnterPropertiesSuccesfully:)]){
        [self.delegate properties2ViewControllerDidEnterPropertiesSuccesfully:testTask];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)aTextField{
    if (aTextField.tag == 1){
        [taskName resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
@end
```

Here are the properties of the Task class...if it helps at all...

```
@interface Tasks : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *taskName;
@property NSTimeInterval timeInterval;
@property NSDate *dateCreated;

-(id)initWith:(NSString *)tskNme :(NSTimeInterval)timeInt :(NSDate *)dateCreat;
@end
```

---EDIT-----
So I tried putting this in my properties2ViewControllerDidEnterPropertiesSuccesfully delegate method but the cell is still not being created...:

```
-(void)properties2ViewControllerDidEnterPropertiesSuccesfully:(Tasks *)t{
    [taskArray addObject:t];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    int lastRow = [[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:lastRow inSection:0];
    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
}
```

Also, if i switch

```
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
```

with

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

then an exception is thrown (Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update')

Comment: Your Properties2ViewController.h is the same as your ToDoTableViewController.h. Maybe post the correct code for Properties2ViewController so we can check that?

Comment: omg how did i not notice that...fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting at the end suggests that the entry never makes it into the Array. Can you check the length of your Array after you call [taskArray addObject:t]; ?  Also, check the value of the object (t) and see if a proper testTask is actually passed in.

It seems you do not actually create the taskArray, just declare it. Try adding this in your ToDoTableViewControllers viewDidLoad

```
taskArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Hmm..you are right. i checked the taskArray after i added a t object, and the count was still 0. however, the taskName value and the timeInterval value were passed successfully.

Comment: @user2533646 I added a possible solution based on your feedback

Comment: OMG THAT WORKED. YES!! YOU ARE AMAZING. I AM SO HAPPY!!!!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH I'VE BEEN WORKING ON THIS FOR LIKE 8 HOURS!!!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try a [tableView reloadData] in

```
- properties2ViewControllerDidEnterPropertiesSuccesfully
```

Comment: I just tried that and unfortunately it did not add any cells :(

Comment: After properties2ViewControllerDidEnterPropertiesSuccesfully calls [tableView reloadData], is tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath called?

Comment: I don't believe so. What would the indexpath be?

Comment: I just tried this:
'-(void)properties2ViewControllerDidEnterPropertiesSuccesfully:(Tasks *)t{
    [taskArray addObject:t];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    int lastRow = [[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:lastRow inSection:0];
    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
}'

Comment: ok well this comment thing screwed up the format so i edited the main post with what i did